# Series function and square roots

Tags: series-expansion

sometimes when using the Series[] function to expand something we can encounter terms that go as fractional power of the small variable we are using to expand.

Imagine the final Series expansion is quite messy. Is there a way to determine if fractional powers are present or not?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you includes a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example)

Comment: `Last[Series[..]] > 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator of the powers is the last element of the [`SeriesData[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) returned by `Series` as clearly explained in the docs.

```
ratPowQ=Last[#]>1&;

Series[Gamma[1/3,z],{z,0,2}]
ratPowQ[%]
(*
  Gamma[1/3]-3 z^(1/3)+(3 z^(4/3))/4+O[z]^(7/3)
  True
*)

Series[BesselJ[1/2,z],{z,0,2}]
ratPowQ[%]
(*
  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[z]+O[z]^(5/2)
  True
*)

Series[BesselJ[1,z],{z,0,2}]
ratPowQ[%]
(*
  z/2+O[z]^3
  False
*)
```

Comment: Very quick solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that after applying `Series[...]//Normal` to some expression you have got something like

```
f = 2a/Sqrt[x]+ b + 4 c x + 3e*Sqrt[x] + d*x^2
```

you could apply, say, this:

```
Last /@ Select[f /. {Plus -> List, Times -> List}, 
   MemberQ[#, Power[x_, Rational[y_, z_]]] &] /. 
 Power[x_, Rational[y_, z_]] -> Rational[y, z]
```

returning the following result:

```
(*  {-(1/2), 1/2}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: This seem to work quite well too! Thanks. I think the second solution is a bit quicker though!